# Vb6 Encode a number with base64

Tags: encoding, vb6, base64

I'm looking for a `VB6` library with a function to encode/decode a number with 20 digits like:

`00001002201200000001`

I need it for compressing the number. I found only functions for encode a string but with the number it generates more chars.

Comment: You'll need to be more explicit in your question. Base64 (encoding, not the number base) is normally used for string/binary data encoding to make something 7bit safe. You can Base64 encode a string representation of the number as you would any other string, but it won't shorten a string, only increase it by about a third. If you want to convert it to base 64 (the number base, not the encoding) then there are algorithms to change the radix but nothing native to VB6.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own RLE (Run Length Encoding) algorythm. It is only going to help you if your data has a lot of repeated characters as in your sample. In essence, you replace a section of repeated characters with a control character or flag, a count of how many times the character is repeated, and the character itself. Your sample would become †`ÿ0ÿ02012ÿ0`. A full sample module can be found at http://www.andreavb.com/tip030023.html.

† The encoding produced a couple of unprintable characters so I could not show the exact encoded string.